# Why isn´t the for loop accessed in release mode, but in debug it works fine

Tags: c++, sockets, c++17

my problem is that I coded server/client application on windows. Now in debug mode everything works fine and as it should , but in release mode the server doesn´t receive or send messages.

I think it is due to that, that the for loop inside the infinite for loop doesn´t get accessed.I also tried to implement this solution with a while but it didn´t work. I think it might be the problem that i call a function in the condition field, because when i compare the i to an integer it gets accessed. Also interesting is that when i std::cout something right before the inner for loop , the loop gets also accessed , despite the fact that I am calling the function in the condition field.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "server.cpp"

//gets defined in server.cpp
void server::acceptConn() {
    u_long mode =1;
    for(;;){
        int len = sizeof(incAddr[connectedSocks]);
        if((inc_sock[connectedSocks] = accept(serv,(struct sockaddr *)&incAddr[connectedSocks],&len))!= SOCKET_ERROR){
            std::cout<<"client connected : "<<inet_ntoa(incAddr[connectedSocks].sin_addr)<<std::endl;
            ioctlsocket(inc_sock[connectedSocks],FIONBIO,&mode);
            connectedSocks++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    server ser;
    ser.init_Server();
    std::thread t(&server::acceptConn,&ser);
    char buf[1024];
    for(;;){
        for(int i=0 ; ser.getCounter()>i;i++){
            if (recv(ser.getInc_Sock()[i], buf, sizeof(buf), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

            } else{
                for (int x = 0; x < ser.getCounter(); x++) {
                    if(x==i){//just that the message doesnt get send back to the sender}
                    else{
                        if (send(ser.getInc_Sock()[x], buf, sizeof(buf), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                            std::cout<<"send failed : "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int getCounter(){return  connectedSocks;};//in server.h
```

The result should be that Server is having a List of connected socks and is distributing the messages to everyone. Now when I am running it in debug mode everything works fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your main logic probably executes before the `accept` call finishes (or even starts). Try waiting for the connection to be there in `main()` before trying to use `ser`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError but wouldn´t it just "erase" the first message i send but the second message will be received and so forth?

Comment: It is very difficult to predict what will happen if you use uninitialized variables.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Am I not waiting till the first connection arrives with the condition 'ser.getCounter()>i ' ? Or how shall I implement it? connectedsocks is the counter of how many socks are connected and is set to 0

Comment: I am not an expert in modern C++ multi-threading, but should you not synchronize the access to `inc_sock`? And to `connectedSocks`? In Java memory model, the compiler would be free to assume that the variables accessed w/o synchronization are only modified on local thread, so the optimized version assumes they are never modified.

Comment: There is no apparent synchronisation on the data you're accessing from both threads.

Comment: @molbdnilo , what do you mean there is no synchronisation ? Sockets are getting written in the array and connected socks are getting increased +1. This all happens in the same object. And the main logic is waiting for connections , so that there will not be an undefined socket accessed. Or do you mean both threads have to run synchronous?

Comment: @Arkadiy yeah but am I not waiting for inc_socks with the condition ´i<ser.getCounter()´? Or what do you mean ?

Comment: @MaestroD You need to protect against concurrent access when you modify variables. This is usually covered in any introduction to multithreading.

Comment: @molbdnilo I will look that up. But cann you than explain to me why this code works when I am printing something just before and when I am not , then not? And why the for loop doesn´t get accessed when I am doing it this way in the release mode?

Comment: @MaestroD Because your code has undefined behaviour, and anything can happen.

Comment: You need to look into "memory model" of modern C++. Put simply, any change to the memory you make on a thread is not officially visible on any other thread until some synchronization happens. This was introduced to accommodate modern CPUs that do their best to postpone actual memory access until it becomes truly necessary. And that is done, in turn, because the memory is much slower than the CPU - orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Building a bit on @molbdnilo's answer, it's quite likely that printing code includes some sort of mutex or other synchronization mechanism somewhere, thus providing visibility. But this is indeed UB according to the memory model.

Comment: Ah okay,thank you for your answers. I will look that up :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks any form of synchronization between the two threads. The worker thread writes data, and the main thread reads data. But because there is no synchronization between them (mutex/atomics/etc), every read from the main thread is a data race with the writes from the worker thread.

And data races are undefined behavior. So the compiler is permitted to compile the main thread as if *nobody ever writes data*.

When you put a `std::cout` in your loops, this "works" because `std::cout` requires some form of synchronization to keep multiple threads from writing to stdout at the same time. So you're effectively piggybacking off of that internal synchronization. But you shouldn't rely on that; you should instead use proper synchronization primitives.